# iPad/iPhone App Dev - Should I store user's data on both device's disk and database?

Tags: iphone, database, ipad, core-data, data-storage

I am new to iPad/iPhone apps/games development.

I am developing a game. The game will need to user's inventory like the current wear, what items have s/he bought. I have read through the core data and sqlite3 for iPad/iPhone. Here is my questions:

1. Is core data(using sqlite3) can only store data on the phone only?
2. Do I need to store in a web database(probably like: obj c -> php -> database -> obj c)

The reason I asked the second question is, I downloaded and installed some iPad games, I play it until certain level, purchase some items. Then, I uninstall/remove the game from my iPad, and the I re-install the game again. When I play again the game, the game recognize my identity, it recognize what level I was, what items I bough. And this make me though that, it could be store somewhere on the developer's database. Am I wrong?

1. Whats the best practices? Store data on phone (using core data), store on online database (mysql through php) or store on both location? Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: if you plan to take advantage of iAP (in App Purchase) in your game, then App Store will take care of such an inventory list for you, and storing another copy in your app side is highly recommended, since the user may want to play your game when no internet connection is around

Comment: You mean, I do not need to store user's inventory? What should I store in my database then?

Comment: You will very likely want to store all kinds of things in your database. Apple only keeps track of purchases made through In App Purchase (IAP), not game status or things about the game that weren't explicitly purchased through IAP. Even then you don't want to query the App Store for purchases made every time the user plays the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a procedure to restore purchases on the appStore.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html

Comment: The procedure is very important and will be tested by Apple. The App Store does keep track of purchases made via IAP, but it's your responsibility to restore them.